# Multiprocess server or multithreaded server?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm writing a simple client server in C. What are advantages of making a multiprocess server instead of a multithread one?

Comment: After you research and learn about processes and threads, you will not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't realistically be answered without knowing your platform.

The rumors suggest that starting new processes on Windows is extremely expensive but starting new threads is nearly free. So Windows environments prefer threads if performance is the only consideration.

On Linux, threads are implemented as slightly special case variants of new processes. They're both nearly free. Pick whichever will lead to best code long-term.

On other platforms, threads might be more expensive -- or might not be able to make use of multiple processors. On those platforms, pick processes.

Of course, there's more than just pure performance. There's something *very* nice about [shared-nothing designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency_and_distribution_orientation) -- if you remove all shared data from a program, you drastically reduce the potential for bugs in the sections of code that are concurrently accessing those data structures. Furthermore, since processes do not share run-time memory, an attacker that compromises one process may not be able to control *other* processes. (Or, it might be more difficult.) Threads would just let the attacker read whatever it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of making a multiprocess server instead of a multithread one:

The protected memory space of each process prevents undesired corruption of one process memory from another.

Disadvantages of making a multiprocess server instead of a multithread one:

The protected memory space of each process prevents desired direct communication between one process and another.

Look at your requirements, take your pick..